# PIL creating a fuzzy image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm currently working on a little project in which I'm trying to generate a random image of a set size with a set palette. Everything generates fine and dandy, but zooming in on the image shows the pixels are interpolated in a way that doesn't look great. I would prefer if the pixels had hard edges, as with nearest neighbor interpolation. How would I go about doing that? See code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env

import random
from PIL import Image

colors = ["#ffffff", "#898d90", "#000000", "#cf0530", "#2450a4", "#7eed56", "#ffd635", "#6134e1",
          "#ffa800", "#6d482f", "#ff3881", "#51e9f4", "#fff8b8", "#94b3ff", "#158d62", "#515252"  ]


def main():

    size = width, height = 128, 128
    image = Image.new( "RGB", size)
    fillRand(image, size)

    image.show()

    del image


def randColor():

    color = random.choice(colors)
    return color


def hex_to_rgb(hex):

  return tuple(int(hex.lstrip('#')[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4)) 


def fillRand(image, size):

    for x in range(size[0]):
        for y in range(size[1]):
            pixel_access_object = image.load()
            pixel_access_object[x,y] = (hex_to_rgb(randColor()))

if ( __name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

Thank you in advance!

P.S. - Python isn't my main language and I'm rusty in general, so apologies if my code is wack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's a problem with your image viewer. I used ImageGlass, and there the pixels have crisp edges. A possible solution would be to make your pixels bigger, so you color 16x16 pixels the same color, instead of one. Then the interpolation woulden't be as visible.

Comment: That helped! I opened it up in Paint and it looked better, but I realized I had been saving in JPG instead of PNG and once I did that it looked perfect